# how to set and use a foreign key for single field in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

```
  from djando.db import models
  class server(models.Model):
        server_IP = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        Server_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

   class application(models.Model):
        ip_address= models.ForeignKey(server_IP,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        ip = models.charField(max_length=100)
        application_name = models.ForeignKey(ip,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        application_start_date = models.DateField()
         = models.DateField()
```

here i want to use ip_address as a foreign key for server_IP
ip as foreignkey for application name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use [ForeignKey.to_field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.to_field) but then your `server_IP` field should be unique

```
  class server(models.Model):
        server_IP = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
        ...

  class application(models.Model):
        ip_address= models.ForeignKey(server, to_field='server_IP', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        ...
```